# Issues when updating to Spyder 4.0.1 with Anaconda - Reverts to Version 3.3.6 when updating in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder

I am trying to update to the latest version of Spyder, Version 4.0.1, on my windows machine.

I have uninstalled anaconda  and done a fresh install of Anaconda, and have updated anaconda and Spyder from the anaconda prompt, both of which have been successful without any errors.

The problem is, when starting Anaconda it shows that Spyder can be updated to the latest version, 4.0.1, and when updating it by clicking on the gear icon, it will run for a minute or so before stopping with no error messages and showing the version as Spyder 3.3.6 with no option to update it.

My current environment is the base environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated